# UPPAAL Verification Error- Index value is out of range

Tags: deadlock, formal-verification, model-checking, uppaal

I am using `Uppaal` for system verification. The simulation is running perfectly fine but when I verify by using this property `A[] not deadlock` it is giving me the following error:

```
_The successors of this state are not well defined.
Index value 3 is out of range. Array length = 3, Element size = 1 in line 1 of go3[id]?_
```

What could have gone wrong there?

Comment: what is the type of go3 and what is the value of id? Uppaal is trying to tell that go3[3] does not exist.

Comment: go3 is an urgent channel, and I made a mistake in defining its array size. This's been sorted out now. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

If your array has a length of 3 the index needs to be 0, 1, or 2. That's why index value 3 is out of range. Make sure your index is never bigger than arraylength-1.